# Assigning variable from hostname

Tags: bash, variables, centos

I'm trying to assign the hostname of a CentOS 6 box as a variable. I have:

```
BOX="hostname"
echo $BOX
rm -rfv /etc/hosts
cp /hardware/dats/files/$BOX/hosts /etc
```

I have also tried

```
BOX='hostname'
```

and

```
BOX= hostname
```

But the variable doesn't seem to stick. No error, it just doesn't copy.
Any thoughts?

Comment: What does `echo cp /hardware/dats/files/$BOX/hosts /etc` show?

Comment: cp /hardware/dats/files/hostname/hosts /etc on all versions of that.

Comment: What's the problem here exactly? What isn't sticking? Is `echo $BOX` not showing the correct thing? Is `cp` not copying the right file? What does using `cp -v` show? What is the return code from `cp`?

Comment: All your attempts set `BOX` to the literal string `hostname`. Are you trying to run the `hostname` command and set it to the output? Use backticks or `$()` to do that. This is beginner shell syntax.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you want to put the name of the host in the `BOX` variable, rather than the literal string `hostname`, use [command substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html#Command-Substitution):

```
BOX=$(hostname)
```